# How can rowBuffer settings in AG-Grid be optimized, especially for child rows in a Master Detail grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I'm virtualizing a large Master-Detail AG-Grid for performance. A rowBuffer can be set at the master and detail level. Through experimentation I know these settings can cause my grid to lock up completely or to work. I cannot find any documentation on how they work.

[Documentation says](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-dom-virtualisation/#row-virtualisation):

> By default the grid will render 10 rows before the first visible row
> and 10 rows after the last visible row, thus 20 additional rows get
> rendered. This is to act as a buffer as on some slower machines and
> browsers, a blank space can be seen as the user scrolls.
>
> To change the row buffer, set grid property rowBuffer to the number of
> rows you would like to render in addition to the visible rows. Set
> rowBuffer=0 to turn off row buffering.

1. How does rowBuffer function on child rows?
2. Is there a way in chrome or chromium to determine a performance score for scrolling in the tuning process?